# Factoring a complicated 20-term polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I'm trying to factorise a 20-term polynomial of the 4th degree with four variables. Ideally, I'd like to do it by hand, but I get the idea that this is pretty improbable. Can anyone point me to some helpful resources on this subject?

Thanks

Comment: Over what field?

Comment: In mathematics, one should avoid saying *complex* if one just means *complicated*.

Comment: Rahul, noted. Qiaochu, as in real, complex, rational, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work great for slightly less complicated polynomials, but only accepts about half of the polynomial I enter.  I'll try downloading a trial version of Mathematica, as that seems to be the engine much of Wolfram Alpha is based on.

Answer (score 5):

My vote goes to [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), a free (in two senses) incredible piece of software. Also available to try online without installation.

Comment: Sage looks a very interesting FOSS alternative to Mathematica. I would up-vote, but unfortunately don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: I use it an awful lot nowadays; to my mind it's a rather impressive alternative (all the more for being free) to things like Mathematica, Maple, and Matlab. I've also had great luck getting questions/concerns answered/addressed by the awesome Sage community.